# How to make changes to the database? (DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In the model of the Post object, I have field `created = models.DateTimeField field (auto_now_add = True)`

There is another field `end_time`, in which - today's date + 1 month in advance. That is, if a post was created, then it will have today's date in the `created` field (January 5, 2020), and in the `end_time` field it will be a month ahead (February 5, 2020).

```
def next_month():
    now = timezone.now()
    return now + relativedelta(months=+1)

end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)
```

To all this, I'm need to add the `is_actual` field, in which -

```
  @property
  def is_actual(self):
    return bool(self.end_time and self.end_time > now())
```

But in this case, I can not use the filter to display the fields, where `is_actual == true`. For me, a filter using this field is very important.

What needs to be done so that I can apply a filter by the `is_actual` field? As far as I understand, here you need to make once a day, for example, changes to the database. But how? To write some kind of custom script, or to do it somehow using Django methods?

Comment: I believe overloading the model manager will let you add custom filters. You will need to write the logic using the actual columns instead of the property.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make "is_actual = model.BooleanField(default=False)" and do what necessary in the clean method. For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
      is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
      ...
      def clean(self):
          super(MyModel, self).clean()
          if self.end_time:
             self.is_active = self.end_time > now()
```

Check here for more insights: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Answer (score 0):

Filter with:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

# is_actual is True
MyModel.objects.filter(
    end_time__gt=Now()
)

# is_actual is False
MyModel.objects.filter(
    end_time__lte=Now()
)
```